# Where is my groovy library located?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, groovy, sdkman

I installed Groovy with sdkman and everything went well, but when I want to make a new project in Intellij Idea I am prompted to choose the Groovy SDK, but I can't find it anywhere.

So my question is where is the groovy library installed?

Let me know if you need any other info.
[image: Prompt in IntelliJ]

Comment: Is this windows?  On mac it's `~/.sdkman/groovy/current`

Comment: Yes. This is on Windows and on C:/user/username/ I have no .sdkman directory.

Comment: I should also say that I installed sdkman through cygwin console.

Comment: so it will be in your cygwin home folder

Comment: you were right. Thanks so much. If you want you can post it as an answer and I accept it. Or I could post it and accept it.

Comment: You can, I'd just be guessing what the windows paths are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing sdkman through cygwin and then installing groovy with sdkman was causing a rather deeply nested folder structure.
I found the groovy library under `C:\cygwin\home\<username>\.sdkman\candidates\groovy\2.4.6`.
Answer provided by tim_yates :)